# Sylius disable Doctrine logging to ext_log_entries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sylius, gedmo-loggable

We are working on a version of **Sylius** `0.9` in which we made several huge changes, overriding a lot of core logics.
Doing so we broke a bit the wired in `logging` or `history` functionality.

Lurking the code it looks like that this functionality is automagically working based on the **Doctrine** orm logging offered by the **Gedmo** bundle

It also looks like that this logging of any update to the model is declared in the models in the vendor.

My question is:

**is there a way to disable this kind of logging?**

It pollutes a table named `ext_log_entries` with around 1'000'000 records each week, which I'm manually truncating every now and then since we're not using this functionality and I don't want to have hundreds of MB in my DB for nothing.